# Homebrew requires ZLIB_W32

Tags: macos, homebrew

Homebrew currently supports NSIS 2.46, but not the latest 3.0 betas. I updated the [existing formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/3c6951ca3072c76af19d096e1332c31de07426c6/Library/Formula/makensis.rb):

```
require 'formula'    

class Makensis3 < Formula
  homepage 'http://nsis.sourceforge.net/'
  url 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/files/NSIS%203%20Pre-release/3.0b1/nsis-3.0b1-src.tar.bz2'
  sha1 '84cc08f56adef72a496c5f01d84481f9cf790608'    

  depends_on 'scons' => :build    

  patch :DATA    

  resource 'nsis' do
    url 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/files/NSIS%203%20Pre-release/3.0b1/nsis-3.0b1.zip'
    sha1 'e796d7d2cc12ac1f26eb17c6db4967f3170ab160'
  end    

  def install
    ENV.libstdcxx if ENV.compiler == :clang    

    scons "STRIP=0", "makensis"
    bin.install "build/release/makensis/makensis"
    (share/'nsis').install resource('nsis')
  end
end
```

The download of the sources works fine, but then the following error is reported.

```
Please specify folder of zlib for Win32 via ZLIB_W32
```

Can I use the Mac OS X version of zlib or do I really have to use the Windows build? How can I specify the folder to zlib? Should this be done via commandline or within the Ruby script?

Comment: When does this error occur? You're building packages for win32 so you'll need to build a win32 version of zlib someday.

Comment: makensis is not a Win32 package, but it's used to build NSIS installers that ultimately run on Windows. There's got to be a way to use a OS X version of zlib, how else did NSIS 2.x installers get built on OS X? Afaik it simply used an older version of zlib.